# How can i POST a reply on a comment in Facebook via Graph API?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, comments, reply

I use page/user token:

request: https://graph.facebook.com/OBJECT_ID/comments?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN

OBJECT_ID = FACEBOOK_COMMENT_ID

result:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#10) ", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 10
  }
}
```

But if i try to use public token (generated via Graph API Explorer without permissions), reply is successfully. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

what kind of access token do you used either it is short lived or long lived token .

If it is short lived then it will give you error after 1hr . and not allowed you to access user details.

Comment: long lived token.... reply to a post is ok (OBJECT_ID = FACEBOOK_POST_ID), but reply to a comment in conversation does not work.

Answer (score -1):

At first you must make video with your Test application with status on developing, and send to Facebook inspection (manage_pages, publish_pages); after approval everything will work.:

[image: At first you must make video with your Test application with status on developing, and send to Facebook inspection(manage_pages,publish_pages), after approval everything will work.]